# Why is the --clean not available any more for Swift command line? How to do clean now?

Tags: swift, perfect

I try to clean the build by following the instruction in Perfect (Server side Swift framework):

```
swift build --clean
```

but it shows error:

```
error: unknown option --clean; use --help to list available options
```

My swift version is

```
>> swift --version
Apple Swift version 4.0.2 (swiftlang-900.0.69.2 clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Why is the `--clean` not available any more? How to do clean now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command was renamed to `swift package clean` in Swift 3.1 and the old syntax was removed in Swift 4.0.

Comment: How to do clean now?

Comment: As I wrote, type `swift package clean`.

Comment: I see. I thought you meant 3.1 only, not 4.0.